# Set Holo theme in older Android versions?

Tags: android, themes

I have used several applications which appear to use Android 4.0's 'Holo' theme, whilst still running on an older version of Android (2.3). Is there a supported way to do this or have these developers designed their own custom themes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look here `SDK/platforms/android-15/data/res/`
There are all styles and related resource data used on latest Android 4.

You can also download it from here:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res

And you can grab what you need from here to your app. Only remove android: prefix to use it in you project. This is only way how to defines the same theme as is used in the latest Android versions.

Comment: Can you put more explanation, as I want to change the tabwidget (in 2.3) style to use 4.2 style.

Answer (score 24):

I am working on this:

https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

EDIT: Moved to: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Might be really fit your needs.

Comment: I am a bit confused... If I understand correctly, one should get a perfect Holo theme (exactly the same as on Android 4) by using the link from accepted answer. Is there any advantage in using your project? (I am not passing judgement, I am genuinly interested)

Comment: If you love these grey buttons and orange shadows, do not download it, there is no use... If you prefer what you see in the demo, have fun ;-)

Comment: As a picture worth a thousand word, here is what a basic app looks like in one extra line of code in your app: https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/f63f72681a76832072ea65a658c9d18db53fa0aa/687474703a2f2f7562756e74756f6e652e636f6d2f3734466338704e7a4d71597055363851416a56353069

Comment: Looks great! But I guess I would get the same effect by using original styles and resources from Android 4 (Holo Light)? Or is there a difference?

Comment: Yes you would get the same effect (and a lighter app) Some resources like dialogs are a little bit harder to tweak than just copying resources ;-)

Comment: Just to be clear: is the app lighter with Android 4 resources or with HoloEverywhere? Otherwise thanks for the explanation and the project, I see the point now - nice, I'll give it a try! :)

Comment: HoloEverywhere = ALL the resources in one click. As this is open Source, just delete and modify what you don't need. Android Resources = Only what you need, but you will spend hundreds of hours importing everything, creating xml files, extending classic Views..

Comment: Great explanation, thanks, and +1 - I finally get it. You should probably post your last comment on the project's 1st page... :) Thanks!