# Android: How to handle theming for older SDK's

Tags: android, sdk, themes, android-manifest

I have an app that is minSDK 10, target's 14.  I'd love to use the Light.Holo Theme (if available for device--and falls back to light theme for older device).  Is there a way I can do this this?

It seems it defaults to Dark.Holo when you target 14, but when I try to add any other theme, it overwrites it and makes it look older on newer devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide separate styles for both platforms to ensure that the correct style will be found at runtime.

In your res/values/styles.xml file, create the following style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light" />
</resources>
```

In your res/values-v11/styles.xml file, create the following style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
</resources>
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, use the following line for your application's theme:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Very, very easy answer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think these answers might fit: [Set Holo theme in older Android versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649634/set-holo-theme-in-older-android-versions)

Basically they're recommending copying the themes into your own project so they're available to all users