# Theme of Spinner in Action Bar displays correctly in the emulator but wrong on the Phone

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-theme

I have a problem where the spinner I use display correctly in the emulator but incorrectly on the phone.

This can best be illustrated with this screen shot taken from the phone (notice the **light grey** background behind the words 'App Priorities 1'):

[image: Incorrect spinner theme displayed on phone]

What it's supposed to look like is like this (taken from the emulator). Here is the text is white and the background black as it should be.

[image: Correct spinner theme displayed on emulator]

I'm not sure what all the relevant parts of the code is, but I have a folder called `values-v14` that contains a single file called `styles.xml`. The file's contents is:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />
</resources>
```

This is the spinner XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView  
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"      
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not sure if the manifest is relevant, but I have this in there:
`android:minSdkVersion="15"`
`android:targetSdkVersion="15"`

I tried setting the version to 14 but that didn't make any difference.

UPDATE: After adding `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to the Manifest both the emulator and the phone has consistent behavior. The action bar is now dark as it should be. But all the lists have a white background!

[image: Now lists color are incorrect!]

Comment: Samsung has this nasty habit of overriding the default themes like `Theme.Holo` with their TouchWiz UI and making them look completely different from any other phone.  That's why your Spinner looks different on the phone.  If you have another device you can test it on, I'd recommend using that. Also, you should look into something called Holo Everywhere to get the default Holo themes to work as expected on devices that override it.

Comment: @MCeley `The Holo themes must not be modified in order to pass CTS.` https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

While Samsung is free to add their own theme (and make it the default) they cannot modify the Holo themes. So any developer specifying a Holo theme in their manifest can rely on it being the same on all CTS certified devices (required to obtain Google's apps and Google Play)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `AppTheme` to `Theme.Holo` instead of `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` and you'll get your dark background back.

`Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` is the same as `Theme.Holo.Light` (light colored everything) just with, you guessed it, a darker `ActionBar`.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked. It's all very confusing, but nevertheless!

Comment: Manufacturer skins have a wonderful way of making themes more difficult. Glad you were able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the phone has the Android 2.x version of Android whereas the emulator is using Android 3+.  This means that the emulator has the Holo theme while the phone does not.  You have to either create your own theme that copies the Holo theme or live with the fact that it's going to look different on different versions of Android.  It's definitely more work to make sure that it still looks good across all versions but it also leads to a more seamless experience.

Comment: Settings / About on the emulator shows Android version 4.04 and on the phone shows version 4.0.3. I'll Google instructions on how to copy the Holo theme across.

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy 3. Your response and this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146424/android-how-to-handle-theming-for-older-sdks) is helping me get somewhere. After adding `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to the manifest now both the emulator and the phone has consistent, albeit, incorrect displays. The action bar is correct but all lists have a white background! I'm uploading the image now to the question.

Comment: What does your AppTheme file look like?

Comment: Thank you @CaseB for your answer, it looked like this `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />` but now looks like this `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />` and it's working!