# LinearLayout with no static dimension and no images low res on 8.9inch Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've been doing a little app for Android today which is an interface to the Google Advanced Search. It basically has no images, and all widget sizes are either `wrap_content` or `fill_parent`. I have used no hard coded pixel dimensions. It basically consists of a `ScrollView`, including a `LinearLayout`, which includes a list of `TextViews` and `Spinners` (and a search button at the very bottom).

I don't know if this is a common thing/question, I couldn't find anything searching today. I have no other Android device than a Galaxy tab 8.9 inch tab. Next is the only thing I have related to the styling in my manifest xml file:

```
     <activity android:name="MainActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

I want to have my app look the same on any device. It has no fixed dimensions, isn't it meant to be that way anyway? How can I fix this?

[The source code is on github, if anyone would want to see](https://github.com/goktugkayaalp/gasclient.git)

here is a screenshot with an Android 2.2 device:

[image: Android 2.2]

This is too from 2.2, but at a bigger res. I'm downloading some other images to see if it is OK in 3.2 VMs, the current image I use is not able to show small phone views.

[image: android 2.2 at bigger res]

From a 4.1 phone

[image: 4.1 phone]

From a 4.1 7inch tab.

[image: from 4.1 7in tab]

As I see, the problem is with my device only:

[image]

Comment: What? Am I crazy or is there no actual question in your question?

Comment: why don't you tell us how it looks on different devices? you can make an emulator configuration to match most any device. build a few and test it.

Comment: and not specifying dimensions doesn't mean that everything is going to fit on every screen size

Comment: I'm testing it with some emulator configs. I've done with a standard phone-sized 2.2 device, and it looks as I wanted. I'll try to add images after I do a couple or more. My laptop doesn't look like the right place to use an emulator though, it takes some time :)

Comment: I am almost certain you should't use text in inputs for field descriptions - they should onyl show example format of input.

Comment: @PawelZubrycki I get you point about that and agree, but text labels would double the number of gui elements I have to create and this app-ish thing is not something to release as a real product of mine, so I just omited them labels, for the sake of seeing my result quicly as this is my first attempt on android.

Comment: You have a problem with themes! Just use override the default one with the black theme and it will do it!

Comment: have you tested it in another real device? if the same problem occurs in another really device then its a problem with theme or the configuration of the device. You can not test everything in to Emulator every time. So, check for if this problem is with your real device only or with another device also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your application theme to `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitle`. This will keep the presentation the same between different OS versions.

Also try setting your min and target SDK in your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: I edited my answer. I noticed you're not setting your min and target SDK. It may default to the highest target (unsure). If you target a lower version, it won't use the newer styles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is as it was intented now. Although I created the project upon api 13, it used sth. else (There were no value set). I set it to 13, and now looks enthralling :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok If I am not wrong you are talking about EditText look & feel in different android version
If yes here is the solution
Use you custom background to all your EditText as follows

```
 <EditText
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/bg_border_statelist" />
```

create selector: drawable/bg_border_statelist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_border_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_border_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_border" />
</selector>
```

drawable/bg_border

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke   
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#B5B5B5" />                        
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
                </shape>
```

drawable/bg_border_selected

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke   
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#FA9D2C" />                        
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
                </shape>
```

use border color as per your choice & inplace of shape drawable you can use [9 patch images](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) also

Comment: THank you for your answer. But I have two questions, one, which file is to contain this **<selector>**, two, will this change the look of EditText items in a way that they will not look like native android apps'?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. It made the app crash. And I actually have problems with the resolution of text in the app, as seen in the last image in my question.

Comment: it builds succesfully, but prompts force close when run on my tab.

Answer (score 1):

> **have you did enough studies on this?**
>
> **what have you tried ?** in your code, you did nothing special to achieve this.
>
> before ask help from others, ask above questions yourself and mention
>   that answer in your question, i.e mention what you tried, then only
>   you can get others attention and get quick reply.

ok lets come to the point.

your question is

**how to make my application look same in all devices ?** am I right.

Here all devices means,

- Different screen sizes
- Different density (screen resolution)
- Different platform versions (for ex. 2.2 and 4 uses its own default
  theme and styles)

So pls go through above topics then **you can do yourself**

Following references will help you to understand those thinks,

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

[Supporting Different Platform Versions](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html)

you can get samples form [android samples](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)

Go through that, try something, then ask your doubts..

Comment: Before asking this question, I've gone through those documents. and I have read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence) part carefully. I've no hard coded walues in my app. I've put the source code on github, and there is a link to the repo in my question. On many emulators I've tried, the resolution is ok.Please see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dXMA7.jpg) image, it is the url to the image in my question, and it is a screenshot from my tablet. I've tried it and it worked nice in any emulator. And I've tried every theme, with same result.

Comment: I've used every version from 2.2 to 4.1 to try. The result was ok. It's only my tablet with the bad result. And by the way, I've searched for answer for 3-4 hours, before I ask, with no result containing a helpful thing to my answer. Thank you for your kind answer, although it is not an answer to my question. I'll upvote it though, because someone else coming here may find it useful.

Comment: sorry g_kaya, I already review your code, u did nothing special to identify which resource is getting from tablet, thats why I thought you didn't try anything. any how, now you know very well about android resource directories, then try to find out which resource directory is referred from tablet, to do that simply duplicate your layout in different layout folder with different label / background. b'coz your tablet using holo dark theme, so we have to write own theme for that table. Note : some manufacture provide large screen with low density. which tablet you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The difference you are seeing is theme related. The TextFields you see in your device are using the Holo theme, as the ones in the other screenshots are not using it.

If you want to use the holo theme in every device one solution is pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649634/set-holo-theme-in-older-android-versions). ( I didn't test but I guess this is not what you want)

In the other hand, if  your goal is to get rid of that holo theme you can just use another theme, black for example. Just replace your theme definition in your manifest with:

```
   <activity android:name="MainActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

And you should be fine!

**EDIT**

Quick edit: I am using 4.1 to compile this. Which version are you using? Try with 4.1.

Your issue is DEFINITELY theme related. Try this piece of code I posted below and if this doesn't work on your device I can think of two reasons. One is you are not using the official Android. If you have in your device some custom rom like Cyanogen that might be overriding your theme. Second is that you have some preference set in your device that is overriding the one in your activity. I find this really unlikely and I never heard about it before but it might be possible, with so many different OS from different manufacturers who knows what's happening.

I don't really have to put it on github, it's so simple code i'll put here, with screenshots:

My manifest setting two themes:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>     
                
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
```

My Activities code, they are the same except obviously for the intent to start the next activity

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.edittext);

}

public void ChangeActivity(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);    
    startActivity(i);       
}
```

The simplest layout I could use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
      
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="ChangeActivity"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Last, screenshots on android 3.2 (left) and 4.1 (right) of using holo and black themes:

Black theme:
[image: black theme]

Holo theme:
[image]

**EDIT**

If you just want to get rid of the tittle bar you can just do it programatically. On your onCreate method and BEFORE setContentView use the following:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This will get rid of the tittle bar, set the app to full screen and won't mess with themes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've tried every theme. The result is quite like the screenshot I posted. Seen your comment too, but the problem is theme-independent. And the device I've problems with is a 3.2 device (Galaxy Tab 8.9 p7300 ).

Comment: That's weird. It definitely worked for me on 4.1 and I can't think of why it shouldn't work on 3.2. I'll run a couple more tests.

Comment: Have you used an app you have written to test? If it is on a github-like site, could you provide a link so I browse the code to compare to mine?

Comment: And i have to ask something. Why do you want to force the behavior like that? If the textfield is using the default holo theme, in all apps in that device it should stick with the holo theme. It would feel strange to the user to use holo theme in every app and when he opens yours he gets the old ugly textfield. You should keep consistence for the  Does this makes any sense to you?

Comment: The only reason for me to set a theme is to get rid of the titlebar with the App name. I don't fancy or have special intent to use a particular theme. And the device has no custom firmware, neither Cyanogen nor sth. else.