# How to create a white Alert on Android using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to show a popup similar to this one on Android using PhoneGap.Is this a native popup? or is it designed by Twitter?

I can't find its name on the internet

Using JavaScript:`alert` and `navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])` shows the default black dialog.

[image: White Popup]

Comment: -I don't think so it's possible using PhoneGap.Whenever we use PhoneGap notification API to show alertDialog it will always shows default black alertDialog.There is no such a Plugin available also.

Comment: This is not related with PhoneGap. It's merely a theme issue and can be easily solved in your manifest file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the native dialog from the Light Holo Theme, twitter definitely hasn't built that. You just need to set the correct theme for your app. You can't do that on the HTML5 layer, but it's very easy to set in your manifest.

Assuming that you are running on any device with android 3.0 or higher you can set up your app theme to Holo.Light in your manifest file:

And if you want to target lower versions you can take a look on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649634/set-holo-theme-in-older-android-versions)

And don't use `javacript.alert()`, that will display an ugly title in your dialog, always use phonegap notification for native dialogs.

Comment: Will I be able to use the Light Holo Theme if I change the Manifest file? I am building the app on eclipse with phonegap (not PhoneGap Build).

Comment: Yes. This has nothing to do with phonegap, it's an Android specific thing. Phonegap only handles the content inside your webview!